# background: fixed no repeat not working on mobile

Tags: html, ios, css, mobile, safari

I am building a webpage where I want the background image to scale to fit the whole screen, maintain aspect ratio and be fixed (so if you scroll down, the background image stays in the same place).

I have achieved this in desktop browsers with the CSS below, but it doesn't work on an iPhone or iPad. On those devices the background is too big (it continues below the fold) and if you scroll down far enough, the image will start repeating.  Anyone have a fix? THanks!

```
HTML {
  background: url(photos/2452.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: This is a known bug with background-attachment:fixed and IOS going far back as I can remember. I use jQuery to detect IOS and serve up something it won't freak with.

Answer (score 142):

I have found a great solution for fixed backgrounds on mobile devices requiring no JavaScript at all.

```
body:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -10;
  background: url(photos/2452.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Please be aware of the negative `z-index` value of `-10`. `html` root element default `z-index` is `0`. This value must be the smallest `z-index` to have it as background.

Comment: Nicely done man! So far this has been the only solution for iOS that works.

Comment: should be accepted, confirmed working in latest opera mini, chrome mobile and firefox mobile.

Comment: flickers on scroll

Comment: @DragonFire I haven't noticed such behaviour on my iOS device. Can you try using the methods described [here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/increase-your-sites-performance-with-hardware-accelerated-css)?

Comment: ok on android, when you put an image, the address bar on top takes some space, when you scroll down it takes whitespace equivalent to address bar, then after a second it removes the whitespace and get the image to cover that area

Comment: I wish I could upvote more! Amazing, have been beating my head for hours! Works perfectly on safari and mobile chrome!

Comment: This works somewhat, but breaks IE and Edge. If you have an element with a background-image with a negative z-index it jumps while scrolling constantly.

Comment: Good Job Man. . . !

Comment: @Vincent Great job. This code works perfect for android even 5 years later.

Comment: I'm having the same issue as DragonFire. When the address bar present on many different mobile browsers expands/retracts, the entire background image shifts. You can use some JavaScript to fix this (give the background image a fixed height equal to `innerHeight` on page load and only change it on window resize when the viewport width is changed), but this can have its own unintended consequences (if the address bar is visible on page load then the background is too small to fill the space once the address bar collapses).

Comment: change top: 0 to bottom: 0, to have it sticky to the bottom

Comment: I'd use `width: 100vw` and `height: 100vh` to stop the bouncing caused by the address bars moving around in iOS.

Comment: I just tried this CSS on Chrome in Android 13 and the background still scrolls up about an inch above bottom of screen before jumping back down again as you scroll to the bottom.

Answer (score 8):

I had a very **simple** solution for this, after struggling with all the methods of fixing this.

i had the problem on my mobile IOS devices.

> **css** (desktop)

```
#ci-hero-11 .widget-wrap , #ci-hero-12 .widget-wrap {
background-size: auto;
background-attachment: fixed;
}

.widget-wrap {
background-attachment: scroll;
}
```

Then i overwrite it with media query removing "fixed" as background attachment.

> **css** (mobile)

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
#ci-hero-11 .widget-wrap , #ci-hero-12 .widget-wrap {

    background-attachment: initial;

}
}
```

initial -   Sets this property to its default value. I think because IOS doesn't accept 'fixed' it falls back to a default value it accepts, scroll.

This worked for me on every device. Hope it helps someone else as well.

Comment: unfortunately this solution based on size is not good. It will fail if I browse in landscape with an iPad, specially if I use an iPad Pro 12" that is 1024x1366... and btw your code tests for 767 pixels but the regular iPad is 768.

Comment: @SpaceDog Then just add an media query based on that device. this was just to get the idea behind the solution.

Comment: anyway the solution does not work. I have tested on an iPad Pro using iOS 10 and 11 and the image continues to scroll.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the efforts of Vincent and work by Joey Hayes, I have this [codepen](http://codepen.io/KerryRuddock/details/zZbvoR/) working on android mobile that supports multiple fixed backgrounds

HTML:

```
<html>

<body>
  <nav>Nav to nowhere</nav>
  <article>

    <section class="bg-img bg-img1">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Fixed backgrounds on a mobile browser</h1>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="solid">
      <h3>Scrolling Foreground Here</h3>
    </section>

    <section>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Quid securi etiam tamquam eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Cum ceteris in veneratione tui montes, nascetur mus. Quisque placerat facilisis egestas cillum dolore. Ambitioni dedisse scripsisse iudicaretur. Quisque ut dolor gravida, placerat libero vel,
          euismod.
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="solid">
      <h3>Scrolling Foreground Here</h3>
    </section>

    <section class="footer">
      <div class="content">
        <h3>The end is nigh.</h3>
      </div>
    </section>

  </article>
  </body>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "source sans pro";
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fdfdfd;
}
body > section >.footer {
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: silver;
  z-index: 999;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

article {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1em;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  padding-top: 5em;
}

.bg-img::before {
  position: fixed;
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;  
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -10; 
}

.bg-img1:before {
      background-image: url('https://res.cloudinary.com/djhkdplck/image/upload/v1491326836/3balls_1280.jpg');
}
.bg-img2::before {
      background-image: url('https://res.cloudinary.com/djhkdplck/image/upload/v1491326840/icebubble-1280.jpg');
}
.bg-img3::before {
      background-image: url('https://res.cloudinary.com/djhkdplck/image/upload/v1491326844/soap-bubbles_1280.jpg');
}

h1, h2, h3 {
  font-family: lato;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.content {
  max-width: 50rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.solid {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

.footer {
  background: rgba(2, 2, 2, 0.5);
}
```

JS/JQUERY

```
window.onload = function() {

  // Alternate Background Page with scrolling content (Bg Pages are odd#s)
  var $bgImg = $('.bg-img');
  var $nav = $('nav');
  var winh = window.innerHeight;
  var scrollPos = 0;
  var page = 1;
  var page1Bottom = winh;
  var page3Top = winh;
  var page3Bottom = winh * 3;
  var page5Top = winh * 3;
  var page5Bottom = winh * 5;

  $(window).on('scroll', function() {

    scrollPos = Number($(window).scrollTop().toFixed(2));
    page = Math.floor(Number(scrollPos / winh) +1);
    if (scrollPos >= 0 && scrollPos < page1Bottom ) {    
      if (! $bgImg.hasClass('bg-img1')) {

        removeBg( $bgImg, 2, 3, 1 ); // element, low, high, current
        $bgImg.addClass('bg-img1');
      }
    } else if (scrollPos >= page3Top && scrollPos <= page3Bottom) {
      if (! $bgImg.hasClass('bg-img2')) {

        removeBg( $bgImg, 1, 3, 2 ); // element, low, high, current
        $bgImg.addClass('bg-img2');
      }
    } else if (scrollPos >= page5Top && scrollPos <= page5Bottom) {
      if (! $bgImg.hasClass('bg-img3')) {

        removeBg( $bgImg, 1, 2, 3 ); // element, low, high, current
        $bgImg.addClass('bg-img3');
      }
    }
    $nav.html("Page# " + page + " window position: " + scrollPos);

  });
}

// This function was created to fix a problem where the mouse moves off the
// screen, this results in improper removal of background image class. Fix
// by removing any background class not applicable to current page.
function removeBg( el, low, high, current ) {
  if (low > high || low <= 0 || high <= 0) {
    console.log ("bad low/high parameters in removeBg");
  }
  for (var i=low; i<=high; i++) {
    if ( i != current ) { // avoid removing class we are trying to add
      if (el.hasClass('bg-img' +i )) {
        el.removeClass('bg-img' +i );
      }
    }
  } 
} // removeBg()
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm late to the party, but this is (unbelievably) [still a problem](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-attachment) as of the 11.05.2017. Here is a simple solution which will also work **cross-platform** with **linear gradients**:

```css
.backgroundFixed {
  background: linear-gradient(160deg, #2db4a8 0%, #13af3d 100%);
  background-size: 100vw 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: -1000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="backgroundFixed"></div>
    <div class="paragraphContainer">
      <p>We're here to make the body scroll</p>
      <p>We're here to make the body scroll</p>
      <p>We're here to make the body scroll</p>
      <p>We're here to make the body scroll</p>
      <p>We're here to make the body scroll</p>
      <p>We're here to make the body scroll</p>
      <p>We're here to make the body scroll</p>
      <p>We're here to make the body scroll</p>
      <p>We're here to make the body scroll</p>
      <p>We're here to make the body scroll</p>
      <p>We're here to make the body scroll</p>
      <p>We're here to make the body scroll</p>
      <p>We're here to make the body scroll</p>
      <p>We're here to make the body scroll</p>
      <p>We're here to make the body scroll</p>
      <p>We're here to make the body scroll</p>
      <p>We're here to make the body scroll</p>
      <p>We're here to make the body scroll</p>
      <p>We're here to make the body scroll</p>
      <p>We're here to make the body scroll</p>
      <p>We're here to make the body scroll</p>
      <p>We're here to make the body scroll</p>
      <p>We're here to make the body scroll</p>
      <p>We're here to make the body scroll</p>
      <p>We're here to make the body scroll</p>
      <p>We're here to make the body scroll</p>
      <p>We're here to make the body scroll</p>
      <p>We're here to make the body scroll</p>
      <p>We're here to make the body scroll</p>
      <p>We're here to make the body scroll</p>
      <p>We're here to make the body scroll</p>
      <p>We're here to make the body scroll</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: tested on iOS 11 and 10 and it is not working on both.

Answer (score 2):

I found maybe best solution for **parallax** effect which work on **all devices**.

Main thing is to set all sections with **z-index** greater than parallax section.

And parallax image element to set fixed with max width and height

```css
body, html { margin: 0px; }
section {
  position: relative; /* Important */
  z-index: 1; /* Important */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

section.blue { background-color: blue; }
section.red { background-color: red; }

section.parallax {
  z-index: 0; /* Important */
}

section.parallax .image {
  position: fixed; /* Important */
  top: 0; /* Important */
  left: 0; /* Important */
  width: 100%; /* Important */
  height: 100%; /* Important */
  background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<section class="blue"></section>
<section class="parallax">
  <div class="image"></div>
</section>
<section class="red"></section>
```

Answer (score 2):

"background-size: cover;" causes a lot of issues on all mobile browsers except Firefox!

This fixed my issue:

```
/* Mobile first */
body{
    background-image: url(bg_mobile.jpg);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

/* Then tablets, laptops and desktops (768px and up) */
@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
body{
    background-image: url(bg.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have been busy using different posts and methods for two days trying to figure it out. I urge anyone to START by looking at the post by Eggs, and mess around with the codepen he and others have built.

This has been the only solution to work properly for me that I have found. I recommend his answer as a solution/ a good starting point at minimum for those of us still figuring out this problem in our own web applications.

I haven't gotten enough reputation yet to comment on his post, otherwise I would. I can't even vote on it yet or I would do that too.

This is the actual code I used:

```
html::before {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    background-image: url('path-to-your-image');
    background-position: bottom left; 
    /*For my instance this is how I have built my bg image. Indexes off the 
bottom left for consistency*/
    background-size: cover;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -10; 
    /*I haven't tested my full app functionality after changing the z-index, but everything appears to work flawlessly right now.*/
}
```

I tried everything with his original code. When I had

```
background-position: center;
```

chrome (on latest android update as of 1/8/18) would lag with updating the image's position, so when scrolling through the website there would be a patch of color where my navbar/URL bar of the browser was. Then it would disappear after the browser recalculated the image center(is what I assume was happening).

So, I recommend making an image around your footer or header like I did, and setting either top left/right or bottom left/right for your position.

In summary, THIS WORKS for me. So try it out if you're reading down this far and nothing has worked yet. Though you should've already hit the original post by now.

Thank you Eggs, and the other fellows you collaborated with on your Codepen.

Answer (score 2):

Found a perfect solution for the problem 
100% working on mobile as well as desktop

https://codepen.io/mrinaljain/pen/YObgEP

```css
.jpx-is-wrapper {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 314749261;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 300px
}

.jpx-is-wrapper>.jpx-is-container {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    clip: rect(auto auto auto auto);
    color: black;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: visible;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    top: 0;
    visibility: visible;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: auto;
    height: 300px
}

.jpx-is-wrapper>.jpx-is-container>.jpx-is-content {
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    visibility: visible;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    display: block
}

.jpx-is-wrapper>.jpx-is-container>.jpx-is-content>.jpx-is-ad {
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0 0 4px 2px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0 0 4px 2px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0 0 4px 2px;
    bottom: 26px;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    height: 588px;
    top: 49px;
    bottom: auto;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
    -o-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0)
}

.jpx-position-fixed {
    position: fixed
}

.jpx-is-wrapper>.jpx-is-container>.jpx-is-content>.jpx-is-ad>.jpx-is-ad-frame {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}

.black-fader {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.75
}

.video-containers {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 0
}

.video-containers video,.video-containers img {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

```html
<p>Salman's arrest has created a wave of tension in Bollywood because of all his projects that were lined up, especially his most awaited film.</p><p>Salman's arrest has created a wave of tension in Bollywood because of all his projects that were lined up, especially his most awaited film.</p><p>Salman's arrest has created a wave of tension in Bollywood because of all his projects that were lined up, especially his most awaited film.</p><p>Salman's arrest has created a wave of tension in Bollywood because of all his projects that were lined up, especially his most awaited film.</p><p>Salman's arrest has created a wave of tension in Bollywood because of all his projects that were lined up, especially his most awaited film.</p><p>Salman's arrest has created a wave of tension in Bollywood because of all his projects that were lined up, especially his most awaited film.</p><p>Salman's arrest has created a wave of tension in Bollywood because of all his projects that were lined up, especially his most awaited film.</p><p>Salman's arrest has created a wave of tension in Bollywood because of all his projects that were lined up, especially his most awaited film.</p><p>Salman's arrest has created a wave of tension in Bollywood because of all his projects that were lined up, especially his most awaited film.</p><p>Salman's arrest has created a wave of tension in Bollywood because of all his projects that were lined up, especially his most awaited film.</p><p>Salman's arrest has created a wave of tension in Bollywood because of all his projects that were lined up, especially his most awaited film.</p><p>Salman's arrest has created a wave of tension in Bollywood because of all his projects that were lined up, especially his most awaited film.</p>

<div class="jpx-is-wrapper">
                       <div class="jpx-is-container">
                          <div class="jpx-is-content">
                             <div class="jpx-is-ad jpx-position-fixed">
                                   <div scrolling="no" width="100%" height="100%" class="jcl-wrapper" style="border: 0px; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                                       <div class="video-containers" id="video-container">
                                          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" class="">
                                       </div>
                                  </div>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>

<p>Salman's arrest has created a wave of tension in Bollywood because of all his projects that were lined up, especially his most awaited film.</p><p>Salman's arrest has created a wave of tension in Bollywood because of all his projects that were lined up, especially his most awaited film.</p><p>Salman's arrest has created a wave of tension in Bollywood because of all his projects that were lined up, especially his most awaited film.</p><p>Salman's arrest has created a wave of tension in Bollywood because of all his projects that were lined up, especially his most awaited film.</p><p>Salman's arrest has created a wave of tension in Bollywood because of all his projects that were lined up, especially his most awaited film.</p><p>Salman's arrest has created a wave of tension in Bollywood because of all his projects that were lined up, especially his most awaited film.</p><p>Salman's arrest has created a wave of tension in Bollywood because of all his projects that were lined up, especially his most awaited film.</p><p>Salman's arrest has created a wave of tension in Bollywood because of all his projects that were lined up, especially his most awaited film.</p><p>Salman's arrest has created a wave of tension in Bollywood because of all his projects that were lined up, especially his most awaited film.</p><p>Salman's arrest has created a wave of tension in Bollywood because of all his projects that were lined up, especially his most awaited film.</p><p>Salman's arrest has created a wave of tension in Bollywood because of all his projects that were lined up, especially his most awaited film.</p><p>Salman's arrest has created a wave of tension in Bollywood because of all his projects that were lined up, especially his most awaited film.</p><p>Salman's arrest has created a wave of tension in Bollywood because of all his projects that were lined up, especially his most awaited film.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

`background-attachment:fixed` in IOS Safari has been a known bug for as long as I can recall.

Here's some other options for you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23420490/1004312

Since the fixed position in general is not all that stable on touch (some more than others, Chrome works great), it is still acting up in Safari IOS 8 in situations that used to work in IOS 7, therefore I generally just use JS to detect touch devices, including Windows mobile.

```
/* ============== SUPPORTS TOUCH OR NOT ========= */
/*! Detects touch support and adds appropriate classes to html and returns a JS object
  Copyright (c) 2013 Izilla Partners Pty Ltd  | http://www.izilla.com.au 
  Licensed under the MIT license  |  https://coderwall.com/p/egbgdw 
*/
var supports = (function() {
    var d = document.documentElement,
        c = "ontouchstart" in window || navigator.msMaxTouchPoints;
    if (c) {
        d.className += " touch";
        return {
            touch: true
        }
    } else {
        d.className += " no-touch";
        return {
            touch: false
        }
    }
})();
```

**CSS example assumes mobile first:**

```
.myBackgroundPrecious {
   background: url(1.jpg) no-repeat center center;
   background-size: cover;
}

.no-touch .myBackgroundPrecious {
   background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that mobile devices dont work with fixed positions. You should try with some js plugin like skrollr.js (for example). With this kind of plugin you can select the position of your div (or whatever) in function of scrollbar position.

Comment: skrollr development ceased in 2014 and even states "mobile support always sucked (because mobile browsers are hard)." I strongly recommend referring to the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Fixed positioning is supported on mobile since Android 2.2 and iOS 5.

You need to use device-with viewport on meta and give the background image with somewhere with an id. Then you will get that id with jquery and give that a height. And of course 100% width

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        #main {
          background: url(1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
          -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
          width: 100%;
          overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body id="main">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var hgt = $(window).height();
    $("#main").css("height", hgt)
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/talendil/oackpmv5/

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to this question: [Detect support for background-attachment: fixed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115080/detect-support-for-background-attachment-fixed/28425758#28425758)

- Detecting touch capability alone doesn't work for laptops with touch screens, and the code for detecting touch giving by Christina will fail on some devices.
- Hector's answer will work, but the animation will be very choppy, so it'll look better to replace fixed with scrolling on devices that don't support fixed.
- Unfortunately, Taylon is incorrect that iOS 5+ supports background-attachment:fixed.  It does not.  I can't find any list of devices that don't support fixed backgrounds.  It's likely that most mobile phone and tablets do not.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same problem, but now it works.
All I had to do was add `background-size: cover !important;` and it works on my Android device!

The entire code looks like this:

```
body.page-id-8 #art-main {
  background: #000000 url("link to image") !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  background-position: 50% 50% !important;
  background-attachment: fixed !important;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  background-size: cover !important;
}
```

Thanks a lot @taylan derinbay and @Vincent!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on Google Nexus with Nougat.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i do and it works everythere :)

```
.container {
  background: url(${myImage})
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
 transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
```

}

then...

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
   background-size: 100% 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this  tag to make 'fixed' positionned element well working on mobile:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Disabling a user's ability to zoom in and out on a webpage is terrible web design practice, particularly on a mobile device that may already have a small screen that makes it difficult for those with poor eyesight to read off of.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my case, I was just using this code and it worked.

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {.classname:before {
    content: "";
    background-image: url(link of your image);
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    z-index: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
```

What makes it worked is the media tag which is needed when adding a code for mobile devices.