# CSS Background image not scrolling on mobile devices

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, background

I have a background image that stays in positions when scrolling down the page.
See JSFiddle here: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yv3k9yof/embedded/result/)
**Code**

```
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background-image: url("http://vrexpert.virtualrealities.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Google5.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
  }
```

**However**
This does not get applied when using a mobile device.. (I'm using an iPad for example). The Image does not scroll along with the page..
How do I get the same result on mobile devices as it does on my desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following: (Adapted from [background: fixed no repeat not working on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26372127/background-fixed-no-repeat-not-working-on-mobile))

```
body:before {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -10;
  background: url("http://vrexpert.virtualrealities.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Google5.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is here:

`background-attachment: fixed;`

It won't scroll with this setting. Just use `scroll` instead

Comment: I believe he *wants* it to be fixed, so that the contents scroll and not the background. He has already achieved the desired effect but it doesn't transfer to mobile. `"I have a background image that stays in positions when scrolling down the page..."`  `"However this does not get applied when using a mobile device"`

Comment: well, but he also writes: `The Image does not scroll along with the page` , so the page is scrolling, but not the background, which he doesn't like...

Comment: There's also the fact he explicitly declared `background-attachment: fixed;`, I think this shows the intent. I think `"The Image does not scroll along with the page"` was a bit of a typo... but anyway let's see what the man himself says :)