# Bootstrap: Background is covering div container, not just the screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image

On my website, I want that the background does not move at all, while the content scrolls in the foreground normally over the background. This effect is working perfectly on my macbook. I have tested it with Safari, Chrome and Firefox. Now when I open the website on my iPhone, the background images are covering the whole div container, not just the screen, which means that the image is way too big and not sharp anymore.

HTML:

```
<div id="tf-home" class="text-center">
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="content">
            <h1>EURE <strong><span class="color">FLUCHT</span></strong> beginnt an diesem Ort</h1>
            <a href="#tf-about" class="fa fa-angle-down page-scroll"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#tf-home {
  background: url(../img/header.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  min-height: 100%
  color: #cfcfcf;
}
```

I hope that someone can help me.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Mobiles do not support the `fixed` background attachment AFAIK

Comment: Possible duplicate of [background: fixed no repeat not working on mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26372127/background-fixed-no-repeat-not-working-on-mobile)

Comment: Yes, correct Aziz. Going go close that one.

Comment: get code in my jsfiddle :)

Comment: Yes Aziz, this is a duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

here you have a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qeL97878/)

```
#tf-home {
  background: url(https://www.google.com/work/images/logo/google-for-work-social-icon.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  min-height: 100vh;
  color: #cfcfcf;
}
```

Comment: Thank your for the code, but unfortunately its still not working on my phone :/