# Fixed background in android and apple devices

Tags: android, html, ios, css, background-size

So here's my problem. I set a background image to a page using the following code:

```
.page-content{
    background-image: url("../../../../assets/pages/media/bg/3.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right top;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size:cover;

}
```

Seems to work fine. Then I added a little more for the mobile version

```
@media(max-width:991px){.page-content{
    background-attachment: scroll;
    }
}
```

I have tried to set `background-size` as cover, initial and even tried playing with the percentages. The problem is that on a mobile device, the background doesn't stay on the screen. When I scroll down, it goes up with the rest of the content.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: so do you want the attachment to be fixed in mobile devices or scrolling?

Comment: Please let us know what you want it to be fixed or normal. Fixed css property doesn't work well on Ipad and mobile devices.

Comment: I want it to stay on the screen at all times.

Answer (score 1):

I believe most, if not all phones do not support fixed background images. What you have to do is put the image in a separate div with a fixed position. The following code is provided by @vincent - [background: fixed no repeat not working on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26372127/background-fixed-no-repeat-not-working-on-mobile)
 It is for the body element but I'm sure you can tweak it to fit your need.

```
body:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: -10;
  background: url(photos/2452.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```