# Adding Fixed Background to Squarespace York Template via Custom CSS - Mobile Issue

Tags: html, css, mobile, background-image, squarespace

I'm trying to add a fixed background image to my Squarespace site using the [York](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/218211197-Using-the-York-template) template. Site can be viewed here ([www.newinkmedia.co](http://www.newinkmedia.co)).

Out of the box, the York template does not support fixed background images so I'm going the custom CSS route. I would like the background image to be centered, contained, and fixed when the user scrolls. Everything seems to be fine on desktop but running into some issues on mobile where the image is enlarged and not fixed.

Screenshots and Custom CSS below:

[Desktop Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyfy6.png)

[Mobile Screenshot #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEkFQ.jpg)

[Mobile Screenshot #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lo4CY.jpg)

```
.overflow-wrapper {
    -webkit-transition: background-color 100ms linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 100ms linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color 100ms linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 100ms linear;
    transition: background-color 100ms linear;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center top;
    background-image: url("https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5ac6c7bd5417fc86faa1ce9d/t/5acd6b972b6a28a577ff7603/1523411863575/newink_concept_v2ai-09.jpg");
}
```

Let me know what you think. Greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: Chrome looks fine and fixed background

Comment: Hi Gerardo - Appreciate the feedback. What device were you using? I checked on chrome/safari via iPhone 7 and 8 with no luck i.e., background image stays at the center and top, not fixed like desktop. Can anybody else confirm? Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

A developer friend of mine pointed me to the following [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26372127/background-fixed-no-repeat-not-working-on-mobile). Pasted my revised CSS below to contain & center. Seems to be working fine on mobile Chrome and Safari via iPhone 7.

```css
.overflow-wrapper {
    -webkit-transition: background-color 100ms linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 100ms linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color 100ms linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 100ms linear;
    transition: background-color 100ms linear;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

body:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  background: url(https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5ac6c7bd5417fc86faa1ce9d/t/5acd6b972b6a28a577ff7603/1523411863575/newink_concept_v2ai-09.jpg) no-repeat center;
  -webkit-background-size: contain;
  -moz-background-size: contain;
  -o-background-size: contain;
  background-size: contain;
}
```