# CSS | Background style - fixed not working in mobile

Tags: css, background-image, fixed

Site: http://www.procolorchile.cl/

I neet to put every image  fixed (after the 1st) whit the logo

This is the class but nothing is working

```
.fullfondo {
  height: 100vh; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-attachment: fixed; 
  background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26372127/background-fixed-no-repeat-not-working-on-mobile

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236158/how-to-replicate-background-attachment-fixed-on-ios

Answer (score 0):

Use css :nth-child(n+2)

```
.fullfondo:nth-child(n+2) {
  height: 100vh; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-attachment: fixed; 
  background-position: center;  
}
```

Comment: dont work
.fullfondo:nth-child(n+1) { height: 100vh; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: fixed; background-position: center; } .fullfondo:nth-child(n+2) { height: 100vh; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: fixed; background-position: center; }