# Why doesn't background image show on IOS as fixed

Tags: css, iphone

I'm building a website using bootstrap and Django. While testing out the UI, the Position: fixed; is not working on an iPhone. I'm attempting to apply this functionality to a background image. I know that Apple doesn't support this, but has anyone found a workaround? Below is my CSS:

```
 width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 40px);
  background: url('../img/BTDARKBLUE1.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover !important;

  position: relative;
  margin-top: 40px;
```

Answer (score 0):

background-position: cover; doesn't work on the mobile browser some time.
Remove this property and check it again.

Also here is the link with alot of solutions for the same problem
[background: fixed no repeat not working on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26372127/background-fixed-no-repeat-not-working-on-mobile)

Comment: Thank you the final resolution was to add z-index in the div in the section. Now the issue is that the button on that part of my site isn't working.

Comment: that Will be because of z-indexing.
Check the z-index and make the index of the buttton about all

Comment: Yep thank you! I just made a separate div for the button that isn't effected by the z-index