# How to make background image fixed in multiples divs for ios devices?

Tags: ios, css, background-image, fixed, cover

I have a web with bootstrap 3.0 with this structure of sections:

```
<html>
<header>
</header>
<body>

<div class="container" id="section1">
        <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 section">
        <header>
        <h3 ></h3>
        <h4></h4>
        </header>

      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container" id="section2">
        <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 section">
        <header>
        <h3 ></h3>
        <h4></h4>
        </header>

      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to put a background image fixed and cover in each div "container". In higher devices works great but in ipad and iphone it doesn't work.
This is my css for section1:

```
    #section1{
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url("img/about.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed !important;
    background-position: center top;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-origin: padding-box;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding-top: 120px;
    min-height: 700px;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I tried various solutions read in posts and Google, but nothing seems to work. 
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779195/does-a-background-attachment-of-fixed-work-in-ios5?

Comment: Yes I read it but doesn't work. Maybe I didn't understand in my example the structure would be `<div id="background"><div id="section1"></div></div>` and css properties would be in background id? Because using position= fixed in section1 id doesn't work.

Comment: Check the answer with 10 votes. id=background is fixed, an has a background.

Comment: @WillemVanBockstal it works like a charm for first div background. But when I add another div bakcground in another section second image overlap the first one :S I tried fixing usin z-index but no work

Comment: I missed the part where you said 'each' div. (Original question title was about 'a' div). This seems harder to solve, I guess you need javascript for that, but is it worth the effort (and performance hit)?

Comment: thanks @WillemVanBockstal I will try to search some javascript for that ;)