# CSS background stretches to fill screen on Safari but not on iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, background-image, stretch

This CSS successfully stretches my background image to fill 100% of the screen area and not scroll on safari but not on iOS. How can I also prevent the image from scrolling on iOS?

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    background: url(../img/background.jpg) center repeat-x;
    background-size: auto 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed
}
```

Comment: I believe your question was discussed here >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779195/does-a-background-attachment-of-fixed-work-in-ios5

Answer (score 1):

I gave up trying to get my iPhone to play nicely with CSS, and had to resort to using jQuery.

In my webpage, I added a `<div>` which I want to fill the screen:

```
<body>
    <div class="cssFullScreen" />
    ...etc...
```

Then I added in two tablespoons of CSS...

```
<style>
    .cssFullScreen
    {
        position: absolute;
        left:0px;
        top:0px;
        background: url(BackgroundImage.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }
</style>
```

..and a reluctant scoop of jQuery...

```
<script src="jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function () {

        ResizeWindows();

        $(window).resize(function () {
            ResizeWindows();
        });
    });

    function ResizeWindows() {
        //  When the user resizes the window, we'll resize any DOM elements
        //  with the "cssFullScreen" class.
        var width = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : $(window).width();
        var height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : $(window).height();

        $(".cssFullScreen").width(width);
        $(".cssFullScreen").height(height);
    }
</script>
```

It's not pretty, but it was the only thing I could find which really worked on an iPhone.

And strangely, this code only worked (on an iPhone) when applied to a `div`.  If I tried to apply it directly to the `html` or `body`, it did nothing...

Comment: It's... something that works. +1 for that. -1(@Apple iOS) for this still happening in 2020 with CSS that's valid for *every* other browser

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    background: url(../img/background.jpg) center repeat-x fixed;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an explanation? Currently your answer is incomplete.

Comment: The fixed property be placed on the same line in the background, could also add another parameter such that the image Top start at position 0 for example background: url(../img/background.jpg) center top repeat-x fixed; because the parameter center is the first parameter this is for X Plane

Comment: It should be in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and it is realated to `position: fixed`. Here was my workaround.

Take the background off the body and put it in its own class.

```css
.bg-pulsing-gradient {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  background: linear-gradient(58deg, #ffffff, #ffffff, #ffffff, #FAF4CF, #F5EA9F, #ffffff);
  background-position: bottom left;
  background-size: 200% 150%;
  animation: pulsingGradient 15s ease infinite;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: -1000; // send to back
}
@keyframes pulsingGradient {
  0% {
    background-size: 200% 150%;
  }
  50% {
    background-size: 150% 150%;
  }
  100% {
    background-size: 200% 150%;
  }
}
```

Just after the `<body>` tag add a the bg class to a single div.

```html
...
<body>
  <div class="bg-pulsing-gradient"></div>
...
</body>
```

The `position: fixed` along with the width, height, top, left will create a sticky box behind all your content. The css background will stay within that box.

This works on iOS and Desktop.