# iphone doesn't display background images

Tags: css, background-image

I've seen this question before, but the answer is evading me. There are four images on the front-page of the site http://miraishii.com. The top image, in the `section` displays fine, but the three within the second `section` don't. They are assigned images with `id`'s gal-1, gal-2, gal-3.

The images display fine in desktop browsers, but neither iOS Safari nor iOS chrome will display the background-images. I'm using the Safari inspector to view the site, the images seem to be loading, but not displaying.

Comment: they display fine in safari on pc, but not on iphone.  Is that the effect you are looking for, with the img fixed?

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because fixed background images do not yet work in iOS yet. See [How to replicate background-attachment fixed on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236158/how-to-replicate-background-attachment-fixed-on-ios) and see [does a background-attachment of fixed work in iOS5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779195/does-a-background-attachment-of-fixed-work-in-ios5)

My suggestion would be to use a media query to target mobile and do the background image in the boring way (just for smaller screens). My understanding is if you want fixed background position on mobile right now, you're going to be doing some hairy polyfills. I am sure the situation will improve over time.

Comment: Got it. It still doesn't work in iOS7 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236158/how-to-replicate-background-attachment-fixed-on-ios