# How to show a fullsize background ok in mobile device?

Tags: html, ios, css

Thanks in advance for your help.

I'm developing a simple landing page here:

www.checkinplace.com

You will see that this simple contact form is responsive.

The normal view is this one:

[image]

When you resize the screen to its minimum width you get this:

[image]

Now, the problem is when you want to see the page on a mobile device.

Here all looks good:

[image]

... but when you scroll down:

[image]

The basic CSS for the background goes like this:

```
<style>html { background: url(/site/assets/img/backgrounds/background.jpg) no-repeat; background-size: cover; }</style>
```

By the way, I have a bug with the button that will try to solve by other means.

Do you know how could I solve this?

Thanks again for your help!!

Comment: Can you add your CSS for the background?

Comment: The website is live here jsalonen:

www.checkinplace.com

I have a simple PHP code to load a random background each time from a variable called $fileName like this:

<style>html { background: url(/site/assets/img/backgrounds/" . $fileName . ") no-repeat; background-size: cover; }</style>

The rest of the code is this one:

html {
 display: none;
 height:  100%;
}

I show the website when the background image has loaded.

Comment: most of mobile browsers not support position:fixed;. try to search iphone css fixed . let me know if you still cant do.

Comment: Please, add the actual CSS into your question to help future visitors too.

Comment: Already added the code jsalonen.

Comment: sorry i didnot see ur code try this `<style>html { background: url(/site/assets/img/backgrounds/background.jpg) no-repeat; background-size: cover;-webkit-background-size:cover }</style>`

Comment: [**See This Post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779195/) and [**This Post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011226/) and [**This Post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429620/)

Comment: Finally did it using one of your posts Chris:

<img alt="Background image" id="backgroundImg" src="/site/assets/img/backgrounds/<?php echo($fileName); ?>" />

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is stretch the background image.
You can do so by replacing `background-size:cover;` with `background-size:100% 100%;`

Your css code would look like this:

`<style>html { background: url(/site/assets/img/backgrounds/background.jpg) no-repeat; background-size: 100% 100%; }</style>`

Answer (score 0):

Already solved it by doing this:

```
<img alt="Background image" id="backgroundImg" src="/site/assets/img/backgrounds/<?php echo($fileName); ?>" />

#backgroundImg {
    position: fixed;

    top:  0;
    left: 0;

    min-width:  100%;
    min-height: 100%;

    z-index: -1;
}
```

Thanks.